# Why tx informations of a specific transfer in BITCOIN protocol will send to many IP addresses?

Tags: transactions, address, value, bech32-address, packets

Recently I send a specific value from a wallet to another wallet and Simultaneously I caputred the related traffics in source and destination.

after that, I found that value and it's related address in different packets which their difference was just in source and destination IP addresses.

Why these information(transferred value and it's output address) where distribute to different addresses and which address is main?

Comment: are you asking about funds being sent to change addresses?

Comment: @UgamKamat I just know that when I extract tx informations from this pcap, I see different packets which their value and output addresses are the same and their IP addresses are different. How I know that which is fund and which is not? and my assumption is that I see a specefic value and it's address in just one packet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is gossip protocol. When you are connected to the bitcoin network, you are usually connected to some random nodes. When you want to send transaction, ultimately your goal is for the transaction to appear in a block. The blocks are created by miners who operate few network nodes. Usually you don't even know which nodes belong to such miners. Therefore you just send the transaction to some or all your of the nodes you are connected to. And they do the same thing. Eventually, the transaction propagates to the whole network – meaning to every connected node. And some of those nodes are miners and one of those miners will include it in their new block.